# Adding '' to every character of a tuple sublist

Tags: python

Hello I'm just finishing my Lorenz code but i have struggle with something, I can't add '' to a character of a list.

```
my_sublist:[(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,1),(0,0,0,0,0,1,0)]
```

and the output that I expect is:

```
my_sublist:[('0','0','0','0','0','0','0'),('0','0','0','0','0','0','1'),('0','0','0','0','0','1','0')]
```

Comment: *Please* show your code for this and explain what difficulties you are having. We do not know what your effort on this is. With what you just posted, it looks like you are just asking the community to give you the answer. Show your own effort please and explain what difficulties you are having.

Comment: You are trying to convert the `int`s to `str`.

Comment: Okey, wait a sec

Comment: Yes its because I cant get this code to work

Comment: @juanmémdez Which is why you really should show us what you have tried already. Maybe you were very close and an extra set of eyes will help unblock you. Sometimes that is all it takes.

Comment: @juanmémdez I know someone just answered. But it would still be great to post your own code to maybe help correct your mistakes, which would be a better lesson here.

Comment: Okey thanks for help me  I am a rookie in this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't adding quote characters, it's converting your values in your tuples to strings. You can do that like this:

```
In [397]: my_sublist = [(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)]

In [398]: x = list(map(lambda x: tuple(map(str, x)), my_sublist))

In [399]: x
Out[399]: 
[('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'),
 ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1'),
 ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0')]
```

What this does is, it converts each element to a string using the `map` function:

```
In [400]: x = (1, 2, 3, 4)

In [403]: tuple(map(str, x))
Out[403]: ('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

And since you have a list of tuples, just apply the same thing above to each one tuple in your list.

Comment: Thanks its just what i need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but by the looks of it, you have a list of tuples with integers in it, and you want string representations of those integers. You can do this several ways by either wrapping the integers in a str() function prior to inserting into the tuples, or by iterating the list of tuples and converting them.

```
new_list = [tuple(str(a) for a in b) for b in my_sublist]
```

This is a list comprehension method and iterates both layers of your list and tuples, converting each item to a string. It's doing:

Convert each item in tuple `a` to a string `str(a)` for each tuple `b` in the list `my_sublist`. Since it is list comprehension you need to convert the second layer back into a tuple `tuple(str(a) for a in b)`.